# Implementing caching for fast processing Videos in MATLAB

Tags: caching, video, parallel-processing, matlab

I am working on a project wherein I need to process video 1 by one and run my algorithm to extract scores from it. The problem is videos are taking too much time to process. I tried to parallelize code using parfor in few places but performance is still bad. How can I improve perfromance? Is there any way of caching frames? I am reading each frame and processing it.
Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Depending on what you want to evaluate, it may be sufficient to analyse only every n-th frame.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I have to analyze every frame because I have to find the frame difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching is certainly an option, but it may not help. It's very hard to speed up code if you don't know what is slow. Use [Matlab's profiler](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html) to find the slow parts, then work on speeding those parts up. After that, profile again to see what effect your changes had.

Here's the basic way to use the profiler:

```
profile on
% call your function here
profile off
profile report
```

Comment: Also can you tell me if caching is an option here?

Answer (score 1):

first,do you make sure your code is support parallel , and you had run matlabpool to open CPU parallel computation

second, maybe you need to optimized your code

thirdly, you can try GPU parallel computation